# Find all entire functions such that $ f(f(z))+f(z)=1 $

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to

> find all entire functions such that $ f(f(z))+f(z)=1$

Can you give me some advice? Note: I don't want a complete answer, just a first step and I will carry on. Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Hint:** Clearly every $y$ in the *range* of $f$ must satisfy $f(y)+y=1$, in other words $f(y)=1-y$.

If the range has nonempty interior, the fact that $f$ is entire means that $f(z)=1-z$ everywhere. But if $f'(z)\ne0$ anywhere, then the range does have a nonempty interior ...

Comment: The only constant function that satisfies given equation is $f(z)=1/2$. So in further considerations I can assume that $f(z)\ne0$ in some point. Yes?

Comment: @luka5z: Yes, that's one way of putting it.

Comment: And we used Little Picard Theorem and Identity Theorem...Thanks for help. Excellent proof!